# Linux c socket data handling

Tags: c

My socket server receives more than 5,000 packets in a sec and the data will be saving into database.

The problem is that handling the data( call stored procedures, select some row ..) into database is slower than receiving data from socket.
As a result, the socket can't receive all data becase the socket receiving buffer is over.

the simple example is here.

**do_something( char *buf, char *res )** {

```
/*
call some database stored procedures and get the result
this part makes bottle neck.
*/
```

}

**recv_data( .. )** {

while(1) {

```
    n = epoll_wait( efd, events, EPOLL_SIZE, -1 );

    if( -1 == n ) {
        perror( "epoll wait error" );
    }

    for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
        if( events[i].data.fd == sfd ) {
           /* accept code */
        } else {
            memset( buf_in, 0x00, 256 );
            readn = read( events[i].data.fd, buf_in, 255  );
            if( readn <= 0 ) {
                /* close connection */
            } else {
                do_something( buf_in, result ); /* the function treats data into dbms */
                write( events[i].data.fd, res, 255 ); /* ack the result */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

my questinos are

1. do i have to seperate the data handling part at a different thread from the receiving data?
2. do i just increase the do_somthing function's performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a fundamental design question to deal with.  The data coming in is faster than the rate you can deal with it.  If this is provably a short term situation then moving the do_something to one or more threads and creating a processing queue may be enough.  Make sure you have sufficient buffer space to handle your "provable" backlog though. However, if this is a sustained situation then moving to another thread or creating a huge processing queue will not be sufficient (although it is still needed).  In that case, you need to either

1. Slow down/pause the incoming torrent using flow control
2. Make the accumulated do_something occur faster than things can possibly come in

It is unlikely the latter is possible so flow control is likely needed.  Note that in some specific situations, a third solution of dropping packets is available.  This often occurs in the design of monitoring systems (for example).

Comment: the huge processing queue is always problem.. i think the flow control is better. thanks